# How to Subtract Days in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, days, date-math

How can I subtract time in MySQL? For example, today is 16 March; I want to subtract 15 days to reach 1 March. Are there any methods that can be used to subtract 15 days from the current date?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```

For a list of units see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 8):

Not entirely related to this question but is related to the title:

```
SELECT SUBTIME("10:24:21", "5");        -- subtracts 5 seconds. (returns "10:24:16")

SELECT SUBTIME("10:24:21", "01:00:00");  -- subtracts one hour. (returns "09:24:21")
```

Documentation: [MySQL **`SUBTIME`** function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime)

Comment: Note that the first example (subtracting a number of seconds) only works up to 59 seconds. Durations of a minute or more must be specified as `HH:MM:SS`.

Comment: Also this answer *did* match the question's title, until I fixed the title.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 15 DAY
```

to keep the datetime precision.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

`SELECT DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 15 DAY);`

for when you want to subtract the number of days.

In order to subtract the time instead, say 15 minutes, the following should work:

`SELECT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL '15:0' MINUTE_SECOND));`

Adding the reference link again :- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible using **date function** in Mysql

```
    select distinct
 lastname, 
      changedat, date_add(changedat, interval -15 day) as newdate
from employee_audit;
```

**lastname** and **changedat** is field name and **employee_audit** is table name.

[image]

I have subtract 15 days from my date - check image please. thanks